# How to Properly Access a Class NSMutableDictionary Instance Variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, getter-setter

So I've been reading up on coding best practices, and the importance of using setters/getters to access and change the instance variables of my custom classes, rather than making the variables public and accessing them directly.

But how does that translate into accessing the values inside a Mutable Dictionary instance variable?

Specifically, I have a custom class. That class has a number of instance variables, one of which is an NSMutableDictionary. For the "non array" instance variables (BOOLs, etc), I understand how to "properly" access them: use dot notation and setter/getter methods.

But for my NSMutableDictionary variable, the setter/getter just accesses the *entire* dictionary, right? So, from my controller, how do I properly set/get values *inside* the class dictionary?

Actually, this question applies even to the code of the class implementation:

Take my convenience init method, for example:

```
- (id) initWithID:(int)ID
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initProcedure];
        [myData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ID] forKey:@"ID"];    
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm accessing the instance variable "myData" directly, rather than using setter/getter methods. I know this is "allowed", but as I understand it's not the best way. But how do I use setter/getters for values within a dictionary?

And then, going back to where we started, how do I do this from outside the class implementation, from my Controller, for example?

For my simple class instance variables, it's just `myClassInstance.aClassVariable = someValue`

But what if I want to modify something inside "myData"?

Do I do something like `[myclassInstance.myData setObject:... forKey:...]` (I know that's not correct, I'm just trying to make my question/confusion clear.

I suppose I can create custom class methods that I call from within my controller instead, like `[myclassInstance editMyDataWithObject:... forKey:...]`

But that seems bulky, and still brings us back around to the question of the implementation within the class itself, and how to properly use setter/getter technique to access a dictionary's member variables instead of directly modifying the dictionary itself.

Sorry for the length, hope my question is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Add to your question the code for `[self initProcedure]` and the @property line for myData that you have written in the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define dynamic properties to access dictionary based variables:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *myData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber myProperty;

@end

@implementation MyClass
@dynamic myProperty;

- (NSNumber) myProperty {
    return [myData objectForKey: @"myProperty"]: 
}

- (void) setMyProperty(NSNumber *value) {
    [myData setObject: value forKey: @"myProperty"]: 
}
@end
```

for each variable being held in the dictionary you can expose its content with a dynamic property not exposing the dictionary itself. From the outside if would feel like the class had dot-syntax capable properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know when your internal collection is mutated or just want control over mutations then you should expose the property as immutable and add mutating methods to your class as you described above. (I do not consider this bulky)

```
[myclassInstance editMyDataWithObject:... forKey:...]
```

Create a method for each type of mutation you would like to support inside `myclassInstance` like replace, remove, insert, etc.

You now have control of all mutations and not allow any outside class to make changes without you knowing.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *myData;
}

@property(readonly) NSDictionary *myData;

@end

@implementation MyClass
@dynamic myData;

- (id) initWithID:(int)ID
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initProcedure];
        [myData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ID] forKey:@"ID"];    
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSArray*)myData
{
    return [[myData copy] autorelease];
}

...

//All mutation methods

@end
```